# How can I Upload Image to Firebase Storage from GridView by clicking Particular Item?

Tags: android, gridview, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

For eg:

```
mRefData.child("Item_Position").setValue(+position);
```

with This I can upload the item Position to Firebase.
In same way I want to Upload The Image of Grid_Item to Firebase.

Comment: You might want to see [this post about save object to Firebase Storage after Firebase Database saved](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41529650/4112725)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is to link Firebase Database into GridView, then you might check this library called [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI) that can convert Firebase Database directly into GridView. Just follow the tutorial in their GitHub page.

And if you just want to store their position, I think you can save any value, any structure you want into Firebase Database using custom object. [Here is some info about that.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

But consider using above library first. Even if you don't want to use it, it contains a lot of information on how to handle Firebase Database into view beautifully.

Comment: I checked these links, but what I am looking is, To Upload Image from Grid view to Firebase.

Comment: On Clicking Item of grid View it should upload that Image to storage.

Comment: You should edit your question mentioning you want to upload image/file, as "upload the item Position to Firebase" may mislead to item position number :)