# Get saved key in Firebase as soon as object is saved

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm new to Firebase and I've come so far with Firebase so far. Like saving objects and retrieving object. I want to know how to get the key of the object saved. In hibernate, it returns key whenever it saves an object. I want to know how this can be achieved in Firebase. Following is the my code, but so far I'm getting nullpointerexception.

```
 ref.child("Advertisements").push().setValue(mobileAdd);

 ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


 StorageReference storageReference = mStorageReference.child("advertisement").child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
 storageReference.putFile(uri);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

 }
 });
```

PS: I want that key to create a folder in storage in Firebase so I can save those images to that created folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DatabaseReference.push()` is a pure client-side operation that returns a reference to a new location that is statistically guaranteed to be unique. So you can first run that and get the key from it, then create a storage reference based on that key:

```
DatabaseReference newDatabaseRef = ref.child("Advertisements").push();
StorageReference newStorageRef = mStorageReference.child("advertisement").child(newRef.getKey()).child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

And then finally set the value to the database and put the file to storage:

```
newDatabaseRef.setValue(mobileAdd);
newStorageRef.putFile(uri);
```